# .net mvc how to render data after table row click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m new to .net mvc and have become stuck when rendering data in my view.
I’m creating a small project management tool and I am currently working on the project admin section.

I’m sending a model that contains a list of all projects that a user has to a view that administers projects. The project list is rendered in a table. The model contains everything relating to the projects, phases, project users etc.
When I click on a row in the table, I would like to render the extended detail of that project below that table so it will display users and phases of the selected project.

With jquery I can do this, but I would like to code this event in the view using .net code and not use Jquery. My main objective is not to call back to the server as I have all the data available in the model.

I’ve searched around and can’t find that much detail about triggering events and rendering further detail on a page. I understand what partials do, but that would mean calling back to the server.

What is the best way to approach this type of problem? Should I just use JQuery? If I do use jquery, how do I then use html helpers in the script, if the script is not in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a form inside each row and a submit button to show the detail. When the submit button is clicked a controller action will be invoked and set the selected row project id which will use it to retrieve the project detail and passed back to the view. You will also need to retrieve the whole list of projects because in order to be able to redisplay the table as well. Your main view model will consist of a property representing the collection of all projects and another property containing the selected project details. Initially the details property will be null. When a project is selected you will assign it. Then inside the view you could test if the details property is assigned and render the details in a partial.

If you decide to use jQuery and AJAX then since you won't be redisplaying the entire page, you don't need to retrieve the project list for the view model in the details action. Only the details. And then simply refresh the corresponding section of the DOM with the partial returned by the action.